# Laptop freezes whenever it isn't plugged in

Tags: 16.04, dell

I have a docked Dell laptop and, if I undock, it freezes and nothing works. I have to do a hard reset and put in the docker to get working again. When it restarts, I get a message about `unsupported splx structure`. I test this, shut down, and start over, but the problem persists every time. Any suggestions as to what I can do?

Comment: When you say "dock" do you mean charging?

Comment: Hi Owen, yes. The laptop is on the docker, charging. And if I need to release it, get freeze. I have to hard reset and restart in the dock again to use it

Comment: Seems likely to be a power management issue.  What are your power management settings?

Comment: Seems to be another problem, cause I try to make an firmware update and the machine crashes. I think the laptop have an issue. Make it check with maintenance dept

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by doing:

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now reboot the system.

Comment: This is completely unspecific the questioner's actual issue, and very unlikely to fix any problem not directly related to outdated system software.